# How to Select a Particular PivotItem in Windows Phone 7 Using WP7 Panorama & Pivot Controls?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pivot

I have started using the [Windows Phone 7 Panorama & Pivot Controls](http://phone.codeplex.com/) for a Windows Phone 7 application. In an OnNavigatedTo event, I'm trying to select which PivotItem to start the new View on. All `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` seem to do is select the header. The content of the PivotItem is not shown and while the header is selected the phone has not animated to it. Here is my current implementation:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // URI is '/page/PivotItemToSelect'.
        string selectedPivotItem = e.Uri.OriginalString.Split('/').Last(); 

        // Match PivotItemToSelect with the PivotItem's Name.
        PivotItem pivotItemToShow = MainPivotControl.Items.Cast<PivotItem>().Single(i => i.Name == selectedPivotItem); 

        MainPivotControl.SelectedItem = pivotItemToShow;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // URI is '/page/PivotItemIndex'.
        string selectedPivotItemIndex = e.Uri.OriginalString.Split('/').Last();
        int index = int.Parse(selectedPivotItemIndex);

        MainPivotControl.SelectedIndex = index;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

Both of these implementations do what I described above. Am I missing a step in the selection process, trying to select a PivotItem too late in the lifecycle of the page, or does this version of the controls not yet support preselection?

Comment: These controls are not the official Panorama and Pivot controls that ship in the Windows Phone 7 development tools, you might want to consider moving to those once the final tools release. In the official tools, the SelectedIndex property of the Pivot control can be set or data bound, assuming the items are already present.

Comment: That is what another colleague had suggested. I am planning on switching to the official controls upon their release and hold off on this issue until then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official release of these tools has fixed the issue. The PivotItem is now selected correctly.